# Is it possible to see if a client is trying to connect a ServerSocket?

Tags: java, while-loop, server

I have this loop running in a thread:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
while (running) {
    ClientHandler ch = new ClientHandler(ss.accept);
}
```

which keeps a `ServerSocket` running waiting for a connection. What I want to do is have an if statement that would check if there is a client trying to connect and if not, it will run the while statement again. This would make it easier to stop the thread from running. Currently, I am just having a `System.exit(0)` in a different part of the code stop the program. So is there a way to only accept a client if there is one waiting to be accepted, otherwise it will test to see if it still needs to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to see if a client is trying to connect a `ServerSocket`?

Yes it is possible, though not necessarily advisable.

You need to use a `ServerSocketChannel` and a `Selector`.  You create the channel and bind it to a port, and then register it with the selector.  Then to see if there is an incoming connection, you call `selectNow()` on the selector to test if the channel is ready.

There is an example at https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector: see section 8.1.  (Note that the example uses `select()` rather than `selectNow()`.  That blocks the thread ... which is not what you want.)

---

If you really just want a way to stop that listener loop while it is blocked, there are some other alternatives:

1. Your control thread could just call `interrupt()` on the `Thread` that makes the `accept()` calls.  The `accept` should throw an `InterruptedIOException`.  For completeness, the `while` should also test the thread's interrupt flag.
2. I think it is also possible for another thread to call `close()` on the `ServerSocket`.  If a thread is currently blocked in an `accept()` call, it should get an exception.

Note: I have not personally tried either of these approaches, so I cannot promise they will work.  But either would be a simpler (and probably better) solution than *polling* using a `Selector` and `selectNow()`.

Calling `System.exit` isn't that bad a solution either, IMO.

Comment: I personally prefer the Thread.interrupt method, but I have also seen ss.setSoTimeout to a shortish time like 1000ms or 100ms, swallow the SocketTimeoutException, and loop around to the test

Comment: Yea.   That has a similar disadvantage to polling `selectNow`